# Chrome Extension - active tab time

Tags: time, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome application and it would be really helpful to easily know how many time is the front tab "active" (duration since the moment it becomes the front tab until the moment it changes to another tab).

I search the documentation but i couldn't find anything helpful so I'm trying to implement it using the `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener`.

Does anyone know a simpler method or any helpful library to do this ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
document.hidden
```

to determine visibility state and a:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e){ console.log(e) }, false);
```

to listen for visibility state change.
You can read more about this API here: [Using the Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API)

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the suggestion :) But i think i can achieve the same using `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener`. I was trying to find something "already made" in order to avoid to implement such functionality.